# True OR False: For any two sets A and B, we have:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is this statement TRUE OR FALSE. Provide a proof or a counterexample.

For any two sets $A$ and $B$, we have $(A × A) - (B × B) = (A - B) × (A - B)$

Comment: What does $A - B$ mean for sets $A$ and $B$? Also, does $\times$ refer to the [Cartesian/direct product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)?

Comment: Yes × refers to Cartesian product

Answer (score 3):

Make a geometric picture. Let $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,2]$. Are you able to represent $A\times A$, $B\times B$ and $(A-B)\times (A-B)$ on the cartesian plane?

Or even take $A=\{a,b\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ are you able to make a direct computation?

Comment: A × A = [(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)]  B×B = [(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)] A - B = (0,1) So, is it False?

Comment: [0,2] is an infinite set... there you need a picture to understand the point. Make the other example with A={a,b} and B={b}.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a calculational way to find all counterexamples.

For both sides, let us compute the elements $\;p\;$, using the definition of $\;\times\;$.  For the left hand side,
\begin{align}
& p \in (A \times A) - (B \times B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;-\;$"} \\
& p \in A \times A \;\land\; \lnot(p \in B \times B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\times\;$, twice, writing $\;p\;$ as $\;(x,y)\;$"} \\
(*)\;\;\;\phantom\equiv & x \in A \land y \in A \;\land\; \lnot(x \in B \land y \in B) \\
\end{align}
For the right hand side,
\begin{align}
& p \in (A - B) \times (A - B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\times\;$, writing $\;p\;$ as $\;(x,y)\;$"} \\
& x \in A - B \;\land\; y \in A - B \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;-\;$, twice"} \\
& x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B) \;\land\; y \in A \land \lnot (y \in B) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: rewrite -- to match the shape of $(*)$"} \\
(**)\;\;\;\phantom\equiv & x \in A \land y \in A \;\land\; \lnot (x \in B \lor y \in B) \\
\end{align}

So the left and right hand sides are equal whenever $(*)$ and $(**)$ are equivalent for all $\;x,y\;$, i.e., whenever
$$
\langle \forall x,y : x \in A \land y \in A : x \in B \equiv y \in B \rangle
$$
(This uses
$$
P \land Q \;\equiv\; P \lor Q \;\equiv\; P \;\equiv\; Q
$$
which Dijkstra et al. call the 'golden rule'.)

Let's see how far we can simplify that, by separating the $\;x\;$ and $\;y\;$ quantifications:

\begin{align}
& \langle \forall x,y : x \in A \land y \in A : x \in B \equiv y \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"split $\;\equiv\;$ into two conjuncts -- the only way forward that I see"} \\
& \langle \forall x,y : x \in A \land y \in A : x \in B \Rightarrow y \in B \rangle \\
& \land \langle \forall x,y : x \in A \land y \in A : y \in B \Rightarrow x \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"both conjuncts are equivalent by exchanging $\;x,y\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x,y : x \in A \land y \in A : x \in B \Rightarrow y \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rewrite $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$; split into two independent quantifications"} \\
& \langle \forall x : x \in A : x \not\in B \rangle \lor \langle \forall y : y \in A : y \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;^c\;$; definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, twice"} \\
(***)\;\;\;\phantom\equiv & A \subseteq B^c \;\lor\; A \subseteq B \\
\end{align}

So in any counterexample, $(***)$ is false: it should be easy to find an example of such $\;A,B\;$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then
$A\times A=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ and $B\times B=\{(2,2)\}$. So the LHS is $$A\times A-B\times B=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$$
But the RHS is calculated to be
$$(A-B)\times (A-B)=\{1\}\times \{1\}=\{(1,1)\}$$
We have thus found a counterexample.